# Remove index.php is working but not for index.php?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

As my title said, I successfully remove `index.php` from URL, but apparently when I type "`index.php?`", it is not working. I have googled everything but found nothing with this issue.

Here is the code in my `.htaccess` (I am using CI also):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$  $1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: i got the answer for anubhava :

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ %{QUERY_STRING}? [L,R=302,NC,NE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule on top of other rules to remove index.php:

```
# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ $1%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, from : www.domain.com/index.php?/testing , and now it redirected to : www.domain.com/?/testing

Comment: but i want it just as : www.domain.com/testing without "?"

Comment: Yess! it is working! Some changes on your code :
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ $1%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,R=302,NC,NE]

Comment: Oh yes I forgot there is a slash already in `/test`. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You can take your application folder out of the system folder and use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

It should work.

And from `config/config.php` file make `enable_query_strings` `FALSE`:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

Follow this which may help you http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: still not working and i have taken the application folder out of system folder before

Comment: Updated check that one now

Comment: thanks shuvo for your effort, but i already got from anubhava

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```